# Critique my docker entrypoint sed to reload nginx

Tags: linux, bash, docker, nginx, cgroups

I need the nginx docker container to reload every 6 hours (for the Letsencrypt [certificate renewal](https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71)).

So I came up with this (hackish method):

```
# Dockerfile

FROM nginx:1.19.4-alpine

# replace the first empty line
RUN sed -i '1,/^$/{s/^$/\nwhile :; do sleep 6h \& wait ${!}; done \&\n/}' /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

So the first lines of [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/stable/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh) are changed from:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# vim:sw=4:ts=4:et

set -e
```

to:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# vim:sw=4:ts=4:et

while :; do sleep 6h & wait ${!}; done &

set -e
```

Why am I doing it this way? I'd like to keep close the official image and make minimum modifications of my own. This way it should be less stuff to maintain (unlike my own entry script).

### I'm looking for some feedback regarding:

1. I know it's a hack. But I guess there's almost no chance of the entry file to have no empty lines at some future point. What do you say?
2. I've it tested with a shorter sleep and some `echo`s and it works. Still, do you see any problems with it?
3. When the `docker stop` commands sends a signal to PID 1 (nginx here), the `sleep 6h` process will also be killed and there is no side effect, like zombie process or anything else?
4. A bit off topic: doesn't `nginx -s reload` log anything? I haven't managed to see a "reloaded" message in the `docker logs`. Not even with the [supposedly debug mode](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/55#issuecomment-165070103): `docker run -d nginx:latest 'nginx-debug' '-g' 'daemon off;'`. Tried both ways:

```sh
docker exec -it ceff1757061f nginx -s reload
2020/11/11 22:12:48 [notice] 36#36: signal process started


docker exec -it ceff1757061f sh
/ # nginx -s reload
2020/11/11 22:13:13 [notice] 57#57: signal process started
```

Still no "reloaded" message in the nginx container log.

Thanks

Comment: but.. [it already exists](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion). Try sending SIGHUP instead of `nginx -s reload`, like [here](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/blob/master/app/functions.sh#L286).

Comment: Why not just initiate the run off a cron job instead?